# Angularjs how to display object correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble displaying my location object. I'm displaying it but it's throwing the whole array and I'm kind of stuck at this part.

My problem is how to remove the `[]` bracket.

[image]

**location json**

```
[
{
    "_id": "5a61acfdd5df1761dd2eb1ef",
    "branch": "Lucena City",
    "__v": 0,
    "building": [
        {
            "name": "mhq",
            "floors": [
                "1st",
                "2nd",
                "3rd"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-19T08:31:57.121Z"
}
```

]

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-sm">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Branch</th>
        <th>Building</th>
        <th>Floors</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="loc in vm.locations">
        <td>{{ loc.branch }}</td>
        <td>{{ loc.building[0].name }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ loc.building[0].floors }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array#join()`

```
 {{ loc.building[0].floors.join(', ') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function

```
loc.building[0].floors.join(",");
```

**Hope it helps!**

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are right.

You can also create a filter say `to_csv_string` that takes an array and returns a comma separated string, then you can pipe the result as

`{{ loc.building[0].floors| to_csv_string }}`. Now you could reuse it wherever its required

I have a demo plunker, you can have a look if you like.

https://plnkr.co/edit/yFJXEiIW3fmL4A7L7kt7?p=preview